# nginx + uwsgi + flask and multiprocess

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have I python-flask script running under uwsgi + nginx deployment configuration. 
My uwsgi.ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
pythonpath=/usr/bin/python3
socket=/tmp/grace.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
uid = www-data 
gid = www-data
plugin= python3
chdir= /home/grace/pyRep/beta_grace
module= app:app
enable-threads= true
master= true
processes= 3
#cheaper= 1
logto = /home/grace/pyRep/beta_grace/uwsgi.log
lazy-apps = true
single-interpreter=true
```

now, inside my script I have a function like this:

```
from uwsgidecorators import *

@timer(60)    
def foo():
    global_var += 1
    print(global_var)
```

Looking at my logs i find:
 global_var: 1
 global_var: 1
 global_var: 1

In my opinion this is due to the lazy-apps options enabled, so after fork i have three copies of this task running and after some time I find:

global_var: 34
global_var: 32
global_var: 32

I tried with the @lock and @postfork decorator before @timer decorator but nothing changes. If I take out lazy-apps option I have problems connecting to the mongoDB engine and other weird behaviours so I think that I have to keep it. 
The only solution I found is to limit processes to 1 but this obiouvsly decreases performances. 
Any advice?!

Comment: This is a completely unrelated and unhelpful comment, which I may regret submitting, but your SO profile icon/picture looks very similar to the popular fascist German symbol in the 1940s. I'm guessing they randomly generate those bit images.

Comment: For your knowledge it's the default one, I never changed it!

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a less invasive solution using a single process and a mule so now my uwsg.ini:

```
processes=1
mules=1
```

and my python script:

```
@timer(60,target='mule')
```

This way I offloaded my main process binding the timer to the mule and other tasks on the main process. I thought of using 2 processes+1 mule but
 also with only one process the speed is ok!

Comment: Using a single process deteriorates he performance of the server adversely.

Answer (score 0):

The key point is that you can not share/use simple variable(even global) to communicate between multiple processes.

IPC methods can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

For your case, I think `redis` is one solution, remember to use distributed lock